# How to auto enable acpi trace after shutdown(s5) and power on

Tags: windows, windbg, acpi

I'm using kernel debug and enable *!amli traceon* for a S5 black screen issue.

Since the fail rate is low, I'm setting a S5 loop by application to reproduce this issue. However, I have to break and type-in *!amli set spewon traceon verboseon logon* every time after system shutdown and power on. Is there anyway to enable acpi trace automatically?

I've tried

```
windbg.exe -c "!amli set spewon traceon verboseon logon;g"
```

but it only works on first time to break.

Answer (score 0):

yiu could use sxe -c.  "....yiur cmd here
;g " ibp   chec this thread [How can I make windbg force load symbols on reconnect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443558/how-can-i-make-windbg-force-load-symbols-on-reconnect)

Comment: Hi blabb,
Thanks for the feedback, as I mentioned I've tried windbg.exe -c "!amli set spewon traceon verboseon logon;g" but it seems only works on first time.

Comment: oops sorry i missed that i think or may be i got cofused by the wording works only first time can you elaborate i mean does it entail a reboot do you use .reboot in the attachef windbg every time or reboot is independent from windbg  can you issue .reboot from windbg if yes sxe i think should break on each reboot